# Deploying github fork to Maven repository

Tags: maven, github, gradle

I am currently looking at this plugin on github: https://github.com/teamcarma/swagger-jaxrs-doclet

Development has stopped on this version but this version offers me what I need, however I want to make a few changes.

I currently use the plugin via a gradle dependency that comes from the maven repository.

If I fork this project and create my own changes, how can I add it to the Maven repository and still access it from my gradle.build file?

Comment: That's more of a licensing issue. But if you can, fork the thing, make your changes, change the Maven coordinates, and push to Central if you want. But first make sure you _can_ do that.

Comment: Okay, if I am just wanting to use it as a one off in my project is there a way to do it privately then?

Comment: Sure, just install it in your local repo with `mvn install:install-file` (still with different coordinates, at the very least a different version).

Comment: You should fork and fix the things, then propose a pull request to the original authors and ask them to release a new version and push it to Maven Central instead. If everyone who fixes something pushes a new version of the artifact under a different `groupId`, then Maven Central will become an unmanageable mess!

Comment: @carlspring it could still be interesting to have, ex. you could have other projects/CI environments depending on the published fork to test it in another context etc., or to use it directly while the upstream project decides what to do with the PR. (which is exactly my case now :) )

Comment: I have to agree with @nha. Publishing a forked version is very common in other language ecosystems (notable ruby and node.js) and it isn't a problem. The forks are usually named in such a way that it's clear that it's a fork and not the "official" upstream version

Comment: What's best practice where the originator has abandoned their artifact and aren't taking pull requests